# Groovy ambiguous method overload

Tags: groovy

Morning all - I see that similar questions have been asked a couple of times, but they all seem to be for compiled projects or those involving Gradle. Anyway, I'm getting the error

```
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method java.math.BigDecimal#<init>.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
[class [C]
[class java.lang.String]
```

when I run this little script

```
String amt = "1"
String currency = "GBP"
String targetCurrency = "USD"

def settlement = crossCurrencyClient.crossCurrency(amt, currency, targetCurrency)

return transfer.amount * new java.math.BigDecimal (settlement)
```

which itself triggers this

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON

public class CrossCurrencyClient {

    def issuingAddress = "rBycsjqxD8RVZP5zrrndiVtJwht7Z457A8"
    String source = "rUR5QVHqFxRa8TSQawc1M6jKj7BvKzbHek" 
    String multiplier = ""
    def resURL = "http://url-string.com/v1/"
    def resourceIdClient = new RESTClient("${resURL}")

    public String generateUUID() {
        def resourceId = resourceIdClient.get(path:"uuid").data.uuid
        println "resourceId = " + resourceId
        return resourceId
        }

    public String crossCurrency(String amt,String currency,String targetCurrency) {

        def http = new HTTPBuilder( "${resURL}accounts/${source}/payments/paths/${source}/${amt}+${targetCurrency}+${issuingAddress}?source_currencies=${currency}+${issuingAddress}" 
)

        http.request(GET,JSON) {

            response.success = { resp, json -> 
                if(json.success){
                    multiplier = json?.source_amount?.value
                }
            }

            response.failure = { resp ->
                println "Request failed with status ${resp.status} and message : ${resp.message}"
                return "Something went wrong"
            }
        }
    return multiplier    
    }
}

CrossCurrencyClient crossCurrencyClient = new CrossCurrencyClient()
```

I can't work out what the problem is here. As far as I can see all the methods are done properly and there is no ambiguity. Can anyone point to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: as BigDecimal has several constructors i assume that i cannot resolve which one to take, therefore the error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The ambiguous method call is the BigDecimal's constructor:

```
Ambiguous method overloading for method java.math.BigDecimal#<init>
```

Further it says that one possible overload is the `BigDecimal(String val)` constructor. I am not sure what exactly does `[class [C]` refer to but I would guess it refers to the `BigDecimal(BigInteger val)`.

The line that's causing it is probably this one:

```
new java.math.BigDecimal (settlement)
```

because the settlement variable is null. In similar situations you could just cast the parameter like so:

```
new java.math.BigDecimal (settlement as String)
```

but it will probably throw NullPointerException later. So just make sure you don't pass nulls to BigDecimal's constructor.

Comment: Thanks, that got it. As you correctly suggest, it is throwing a NullPointerException, but that's straightforward to sort out.

Answer (score 1):

As the exception says, `settlement` is `null` so Groovy doesn't know which constructor of `BigInteger` to call (as null could be either).

It is null because of:

```
            if(json.success){
                multiplier = json?.source_amount?.value
            }
```

so if `json` or `source_amount` are null, then `multiplier` is null, so you return null...

You can either stop your method returning null...  Or change the constructor to:

```
return transfer.amount * new BigDecimal((String)settlement)
```